# Where is the ec2 trustore located?

Tags: amazon-ec2, spring-kafka, truststore

Where is the ec2 trustore located?
We need the trustore.jks and password to connect to a AWS MSK cluster from a spring boot kafka app.
I am referring to SSL  keystore and truststore folders with jks

Comment: What is `trustore`? Please edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: SSL trustore-Got the guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html.